# Type parameter constraint doesn't seem to apply to the returned type

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I am currently working on an implementation of lazy locating self hosted WCF services. These services define their contracts in a common interface to client and host which has to be inherited from `IWCFServiceBase`.

After the `WCFHost` hosts an interface specified by a type parameter constrained by `IWCFServiceBase`: `public class WCFHost<T> where T : WCFServiceBase, IWCFServiceBase` a client can subscribe to this host by specifying the interface and a service identifier: `public class WCFClient<T> : IDisposable where T : IWCFServiceBase`. So far this functionality works flawlessly.

Now I wanted to try to sort of "Lazy-Discover" services and keep a usable channel for each discovered service open. This functionality is provided by a locator which holds all discovered services in this structure: `public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<IWCFServiceBase, WCFClient<IWCFServiceBase>>> Services;`

Now assuming a service has been used before so it is already discovered and saved in the dictionary I use the following code to retrieve it:

```
 public WCFClient<T> GetMicroService<T>(string servicename, T contract) where T : IWCFServiceBase
 {
      if (this.Services.ContainsKey(servicename) && this.Services[servicename].ContainsKey(contract))
      {
          return this.Services[servicename][contract];
      }
  }
```

The type `Client.WCFClient<WCFCommunication.IWCFServiceBase>` cannot be implicitly converted to `Client.WCFClient<T>`.

Obviously this is the case `T != IWCFServiceBase` except if you take the type constraint `where T : IWCFServiceBase` into account.

So, why isn't C# doing that and what did I get wrong? I feel like there must be a big mistake in how I am trying to use generics.

Comment: suppose `T` is `FirstService`, and dictionary contains `WCFClient<SecondService>`. Both services are `IWCFServiceBase`, but they are different and not convertible to each other. So that's what compiler tells you - arbitrary `WCFClient<IWCFServiceBase>` is not always `WCFClient<YourSpecificType>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner dictionary only "knows" that it has a `WCFCLient<IWCFServiceBase>` as the value. There's nothing you from putting *any* `WCFCLient<IWCFServiceBase>` in there. You may have ensured that you only put the right values in there, but the compiler can't tell that. You just need to add a cast to show that you're sure.

I'd use `TryGetValue` here instead of `ContainsKey`, as well. Assuming you can use C# 7:

```
public WCFClient<T> GetMicroService<T>(string serviceName, T contract)
    where T : IWCFServiceBase
{
    if (Services.TryGetValue(serviceName, out var service) &&
        service.TryGetValue(contract, out var client))
    {
        // client will just be WCFClient<IWCFServiceBase>, so we need to cast
        return (WCFClient<T>) client;
    }
    // Throw an exception or whatever...
}
```

Or with separate variable declarations for the `out` parameters:

```
public WCFClient<T> GetMicroService<T>(string serviceName, T contract)
    where T : IWCFServiceBase
{
    Dictionary<IWCFServiceBase, WCFClient<IWCFServiceBase>> service;
    WCFClient<IWCFServiceBase> client;
    if (Services.TryGetValue(serviceName, out service) &&
        service.TryGetValue(contract, out client))
    {
        // client will just be WCFClient<IWCFServiceBase>, so we need to cast
        return (WCFClient<T>) (object) client;
    }
    // Throw an exception or whatever...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. With this information I was able to solve my problem and rewrite my code accordingly (now fallen back to using ``Type`` and boxing the client into object). Although you might want to edit your answer as the cast won't work and still produce the same error.

Comment: @R.Bechtel: I doubt that it would be the *same* error. I've added a cast to object though, which is why I assume you had to do too. Note that won't perform any boxing unless `WCFClient<T>` is a value type.

Comment: The cast to object seems to be necessary after all I can tell. I Actually gone that far to directly use ``object`` instead of ``WCFClient<IWCServieBase>`` in ``Services`` previously. But thanks for pointing out that it is an option to just cast to ``object`` first.